# undefined reference to `__cudaPopCallConfiguration'

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, fortran

I am trying to compile a cuda code that I have received from Github (https://github.com/exafmm/exafmm-alpha).

The Makefile.include contains:

```
.SUFFIXES: .cxx .cu .f90 .o
.PHONY: docs

CUDA_INSTALL_PATH = /usr/local/cuda

#DEVICE  = cpu
DEVICE  = gpu

CXX     = mpicxx -g -O3 -lstdc++ -fPIC -fopenmp -ffast-math -funroll-loops -rdynamic -Wfatal-errors -I../include
NVCC    = nvcc -Xcompiler "-fopenmp -O3" -lstdc++ -use_fast_math -I../include
FC      = mpif90 -g -O3 -fPIC -fopenmp -funroll-loops -rdynamic -I../include
FCC      = mpif90 -c -O3 -fPIC -fopenmp -funroll-loops -rdynamic -I../include
LFLAGS  = -D$(DEVICE) -lstdc++ -ldl -lm
LFLAGS  += -lmpi_cxx
LFLAGS  += -lpthread

ifeq ($(DEVICE),gpu)
LFLAGS  += -lcudart
endif
OBJECT  = ../kernel/$(DEVICE)Laplace.o ../kernel/$(DEVICE)BiotSavart.o\
        ../kernel/$(DEVICE)Stretching.o ../kernel/$(DEVICE)Gaussian.o\
        ../kernel/$(DEVICE)CoulombVdW.o

.cxx.o:
        $(CXX) -c $? -o $@ $(LFLAGS)
.cu.o:
        $(NVCC) -c $? -o $@ $(LFLAGS)
.f90.o:
        $(FC) -c $? -o $@
```

And the Makefile is:

```
include ../Makefile.include
lib_parallel_ij: parallel_wrapper_ij.o $(OBJECT)
        ar -cr libfmm.a parallel_wrapper_ij.o $(OBJECT)
        ranlib libfmm.a

test_parallel_ij: test_parallel_ij.o
        make lib_parallel_ij
        $(FC) $? -L. -lfmm $(LFLAGS)
        mpirun -np 2 ./a.out
```

When I tried to compile the code, I get the following errors.

```
mpif90 -g -O3 -fPIC -fopenmp -funroll-loops -rdynamic -I../include -c test_parallel_ij.f90 -o test_parallel_ij.o
make lib_parallel_ij
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/bidesh/panelCode/UVLM/NVLM_FMM/solver_single_rotor_try/exafmm-alpha-vortex/wrapper'
mpicxx -g -O3 -lstdc++ -fPIC -fopenmp -ffast-math -funroll-loops -rdynamic -Wfatal-errors -I../include -c parallel_wrapper_ij.cxx -o parallel_wrapper_ij.o -Dgpu -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lmpi_cxx -lpthread -lcudart
nvcc -Xcompiler "-fopenmp -O3" -lstdc++ -use_fast_math -I../include -c ../kernel/gpuLaplace.cu -o ../kernel/gpuLaplace.o -Dgpu -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lmpi_cxx -lpthread -lcudart
nvcc -Xcompiler "-fopenmp -O3" -lstdc++ -use_fast_math -I../include -c ../kernel/gpuBiotSavart.cu -o ../kernel/gpuBiotSavart.o -Dgpu -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lmpi_cxx -lpthread -lcudart
../kernel/gpuBiotSavart.cu(542): warning #177-D: variable "SQRT4PI" was declared but never referenced

../kernel/gpuBiotSavart.cu(548): warning #550-D: variable "r" was set but never used

nvcc -Xcompiler "-fopenmp -O3" -lstdc++ -use_fast_math -I../include -c ../kernel/gpuStretching.cu -o ../kernel/gpuStretching.o -Dgpu -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lmpi_cxx -lpthread -lcudart
nvcc -Xcompiler "-fopenmp -O3" -lstdc++ -use_fast_math -I../include -c ../kernel/gpuGaussian.cu -o ../kernel/gpuGaussian.o -Dgpu -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lmpi_cxx -lpthread -lcudart
nvcc -Xcompiler "-fopenmp -O3" -lstdc++ -use_fast_math -I../include -c ../kernel/gpuCoulombVdW.cu -o ../kernel/gpuCoulombVdW.o -Dgpu -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lmpi_cxx -lpthread -lcudart
ar -cr libfmm.a parallel_wrapper_ij.o ../kernel/gpuLaplace.o ../kernel/gpuBiotSavart.o ../kernel/gpuStretching.o ../kernel/gpuGaussian.o ../kernel/gpuCoulombVdW.o
ranlib libfmm.a
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bidesh/panelCode/UVLM/NVLM_FMM/solver_single_rotor_try/exafmm-alpha-vortex/wrapper'
mpif90 -g -O3 -fPIC -fopenmp -funroll-loops -rdynamic -I../include test_parallel_ij.o -L. -lfmm -Dgpu -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lmpi_cxx -lpthread -lcudart
./libfmm.a(gpuLaplace.o): In function `LaplaceL2P_GPU(int*, int*, double*, double*)':
tmpxft_0000397c_00000000-6_gpuLaplace.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `__cudaPopCallConfiguration'
....
./libfmm.a(gpuLaplace.o): In function `Kernel::LaplaceL2P()':
tmpxft_0000397c_00000000-6_gpuLaplace.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3e06): undefined reference to `__cudaPushCallConfiguration'
....
./libfmm.a(gpuCoulombVdW.o): In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00003a87_00000000-6_gpuCoulombVdW.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x189): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinaryEnd'
....
```

I tried to find the installation of cuda:

```
whereis cuda
cuda: /usr/lib/cuda /usr/include/cuda.h /usr/local/cuda
```

I could not fix the error, can anyone give any hint to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: You have a mixed CUDA configuration on your machine.  One version of CUDA is 8.0 or older (the one that is providing `nvcc`) and the library you are linking against with your `mpif90` link step is CUDA 9.0 or newer.  1. find out the path to the actual `nvcc` in use via `which nvcc`.  With that information update your link command (`LFLAGS  += -lcudart`) so that prior to `-lcudart` you are also passing `-L/path/to/lib/based/on/which/nvcc`  Obviously you need to change that fake path to the one that is actually reported by `which nvcc`, substituting `/lib` or `/lib64` for `/bin`.

Comment: Sorry, I have 8.0/9.0 reversed above.  The thing providing `nvcc` is CUDA 9.0 or newer, and the library you are linking against is CUDA 8.0 or older.

Comment: @RobertCrovella  I am new to Linux. As I understand from your reply there was some conflict with different versions. I removed cuda directory /usr/lib/cuda. Still, it gives the same error.

Comment: @BideshSengupta: Are you sure you cleaned up the intermediate files before attempting a rebuild?

Comment: @einpoklum Can you kindly tell me how to be sure about cleaning up the intermediate files?

Comment: @BideshSengupta: All of those `.o` files resulting from compilation, plus anything else your Makefile has a rule for creating, and isn't the final output.

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks a lot for such clear explanations.